# Quelle est l'origine du sens au figuré de la la locution « danse du ventre » etc. ?

Tags: sens, locutions, origine-ou-raison, connotation

Dans le cadre d'une autre question on a évoqué le sens au figuré de la locution nominale « danse du ventre » soit la « manœuvre de séduction ou de complaisance » ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/danse_du_ventre)) ; on donne trois exemples où la locution est introduite avec le verbe *faire* et où ça semble connoté négativement. On n'a pas identifié ce sens ailleurs mais au moins un locuteur semble l'avoir reconnu.

1. Quand le sens au figuré est-il attesté ?
2. S'agit-il d'une locution nominale ou verbale (faire...) ;
   accepterait-ton par exemple « il y là assurément danse du ventre » ?
3. Le sens présenté au Wiktionnaire est-il exact, est-ce davantage le
   subterfuge (la manœuvre) ou l'envoûtement (de séduction ou de complaisance) plus neutre ou autrement ?

Answer (score 3):

1. Il est probable que le sens figuré a été utilisé beaucoup plus tôt, mais un ouvrage de 1997 le met dans la bouche de Jacques Chirac ou Alain Juppé:

> En tête à tête, Alain Juppé et Jacques Chirac ironisent : « Balladur fait la danse du ventre devant les centristes. »
> *Jacques, Édouard, Charles, Philippe et les autres*, Christine Clerc

2. Les formes avec *faire* sont quasiment toujours utilisées.
3. La définition n'est pas fausse, mais ne mentionne pas la flatterie et l'hypocrisie qui sont souvent associés à ce comportement. Cette danse du ventre à quelque chose en commun (le ventre !) avec un mot que je viens de découvrir: l'*[aplaventrisme](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8366207)*.

Answer (score 1):

Cela semble beaucoup utilisé en politique, notamment dans un registre un peu "irrévencieux".

Une petite recherche dans [google actualités](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22danse+du+ventre%22) ou dans [twitter](https://twitter.com/search?q=danse%20du%20ventre&src=typed_query) nous offre quelques exemples :

- par exemple pour accuser ceux du camp d'en face d'en faire trop pour séduire les électeurs.

> [le RN (...) fait déjà la danse du ventre aux électeurs égarés](https://www.lamontagne.fr/paris-75000/actualites/debout-sur-la-poutre_13948461/)

- ou encore pour reprocher à d'autres un manque de sincérité dans leurs effort de séduction.

> [Macron fait la danse du ventre à 500 patrons d’entreprises](https://www.lefigaro.fr/societes/macron-fait-la-danse-du-ventre-a-500-patrons-d-entreprises-de-taille-intermediaire-eti-20200121)

Le tout étant assez largement péjoratif.

En revanche, je n'ai pas plus d'élément concernant l'historique de cette expression.